# expand and hide jQuery

Tags: jquery, expand

Can anyone point out where the following is "Bad code"? Unfortunately I can't quite link/display the page where it is on, but since September this has served the purpose of showing hidden content when an appropriate button is clicked. Now for some reason, it's been reported to me that the code is "bad code" and the function is broken and needs to be re-written. The idea behind this code is to have titles with an expanding button (expandBtn.png) and when that button is clicked, the hidden content is revealed and the expandBtn.png then will turn into a hideBtn.png that will conceal the content again once clicked.

I don't know where the script is "broken" or what it's doing/not doing that it should or shouldn't, but apparently another developer was able to glance at the code w/o seeing the page and say it is wrong, so I'm hoping someone here is skilled enough to look at the code and perhaps see what isn't right. Thanks in advance.

```
     // FOR EACH SECTION THAT HAS THE HIDDEN CONTENT BE SURE TO CHANGE THE ID OF THE IMG IN THE MARKUP TO HAVE THE SINGULAR FORM OF THE #SWITCH ID 

    $(document).ready(function()     
    { $('div.hiddenComplexity').hide();});
            $('div.expandingBtnComplexity').click(function()
          {$('div.hiddenComplexity').slideToggle('fast');
            }); 

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var openIconPath = 'openIconPath';
    var closedIconPath = 'closedIconPath';

    $('#switch_images').click(function(){

    if($(this).attr('src') == openIconPath){
     $(this).attr('src', closedIconPath);
    }else{ 
     $(this).attr('src',openIconPath);
    }
   });
   });
   //
   //

   $(document).ready(function(){

   var openIconPath = '/resource/uploads_scope/img/expandBtn.png';
   var closedIconPath = '/resource/uploads_scope/img/hideBtn.png';

   $('#switch_image').click(function(){

   if($(this).attr('src') == openIconPath){
     $(this).attr('src', closedIconPath);
   }else{ 
     $(this).attr('src',openIconPath);
   }
   });
   });
```

Comment: If it works, then it's not "broken". This sounds like something you should ask the other developer, regardless of what answer(s) you get here.

Comment: Start by combining the `ready` functions if this is all one file. Then I would suggest, depending on which version of jquery you are using looking to use some sort of delegation such as `on`, `delegate`, or `live`. These methods will bind events to current and future elements.For the section with image paths, you might look into using a different element than an image and changing the image through adding/removing classes. Overall you need to clean up the duplicate code.

Comment: It may be helpful if you could include a snippet of the html...

Comment: I'm no able to ask the other developer. It was relayed to me via 3rd party, asking if I heard that my script was broken. When asking for specifics, he said he didn't know. However, I checked the pages it's on and it sees to be working fine as it ever was.

Comment: scrappedcola - Yes I indeed would rather not use the image element, but unfortunately I am CHAINED to the designer's specs and mock up. I'm not even included in meetings where the design and development discussions take place..only handed a design and told to code it. I'll look into your suggestions though, thanks.

Comment: You have two `$('#switch_images').click(function(){`, one which seems to set a path, the other, well, not a path. I would think one of those functions can go away. Without an example of the markup it's acting on, it's hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: Ted - one is $('#switch_image') and one is $('#switch_images'), necessary I do believe to turn the collapse/hide image that results when expanded back into a "show" image. My desire is to just have it be a simple "+" or "-" text.

Answer (score 2):

Quickly, you can:

1. Eliminate the redundant ready function
2. Collapse the selectors so that the retrieval isn't computed multiple times

Result:

```
$(function () {
    // Set the selectors
    var $hiddenComplexity = $('div.hiddenComplexity'),
        $expandingBtnComplexity = $('div.expandingBtnComplexity'),
        $switchImage = $('#switch_image');

    // Setup the icon paths
    var openIconPath = '/resource/uploads_scope/img/expandBtn.png',
        closedIconPath = '/resource/uploads_scope/img/hideBtn.png';

    $hiddenComplexity.hide();

    // Bind the handlers
    $switchImage.click(function () {
        var src = $switchImage.attr('src');
        switchImage.attr('src', src == openIconPath ? closedIconPath : openIconPath);
    });

    $expandingBtnComplexity.click(function () {
        $hiddenComplexity.slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Either way, perhaps you should consider a more OOP approach.

Comment: I used this which works cool...but I can't seem to get the images to toggle depending upon if the hidden div is open or closed. Here's a site that I have it on that I can show:
http://www.flyjay.com/ notice how the image does not toggle. You can see the code via view source.